# Excel VBA save to PDF not refreshing graph in For Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA macro that loops through rows on a Worksheet named Graph Calculations and then saves a different worksheet Graph Wheel as a PDF. The problem is Graph Wheel does not refresh itself with data from "Graph Calculations".A(c var):R(c var). The graph saves to pdf correctly for each value in the c var, so I know the rest of the code works. It just does not refresh Graph Calculations. I have tried activating the row in Graph Calculations and then trying to refresh but cannot get syntax correct of referencing A(c var):R(c var)

Code as follows:

```vb
Sub PrintSelectionToPDF()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim c As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Graph Calculations")
        Set rng = Intersect(.Range("A:A"), .UsedRange)
    End With

    For Each c In rng

        'Skip Row 1 (headers)and stop at first null'
        If c.Row > 1 And Not IsNull(c.Row) Then

            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Wheel Graph")
        'Change the value in Wheel Graph B2 to c.Value'
                .Range("B2").Value = c.Value
        ' I have tried the following '
        ' Sheets("Graph Calculations").Activate'
        'ActiveSheet.Cells(("A")c.value:("R")c.Value).Select'
                .Calculate
        'Sheets("Wheel Graph").Activate'
                .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
                    ThisWorkbook.Path & "\testfilename_" & CStr(c.Value) & ".pdf", Quality:= _
                    xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                    OpenAfterPublish:=True

            End With

        End If
        
    Next c
 End Sub
```

Comment: What to be calculated? `.Range("B2").Value = c.Value` copy the cell value, even if it has a formula. Is there a real graph, or only a sheet name? What are you expecting from this "not refreshing graph"?

Comment: The Sheet has many graphs but references another sheet for a range.

Comment: The following code may do the trick but c variable is a range object and I think needs to be an Integer when referencing it as cell value . I want to select a row no based on c variable      Sheets("Graph Calculations").Range(Cells(c, 1), Cells(c, 18)).Select